# mark.js Highlighting specific words

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I have a monkey script to highlight parts of a site using mark.js with jquery. I have a value in the array called "New York". I would like it so when it finds the word "new" or "york" individually, it doesn't highlight it, just the string "new york"
Code:

```
var instance = new Mark(document.querySelector("body"));
instance.mark(["Total%20Loss%20Reported", "NY", "NJ", "stolen", "Canada", "frame%20damage", "moderate", "New%20Jersey", "New%20York", "structural", "accident", "damage", "damaged"], {
           "accuracy": "exactly"
});
$('mark').css({'background':'transparent' , 'color':'red'});
```

Edit: I tried the %20 for spaces instead of a space, and it didn't work, also tried / /g

Comment: @wOxxOm It will highlight the string "new" or "york", not just "New York"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](https://markjs.io/) says to use `separateWordSearch` option:

```
instance.mark(["New York"], {
    accuracy: "exactly",
    separateWordSearch: false,
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess I'm just really stupid and didn't see that option, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable the option `separateWordSearch`. Set it to false and it will highlight only "new york" and not single  words of it.  Btw.: Don't use "%20" for spaces.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://markjs.io/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I'm just really stupid and didn't see that option, Thanks dude!

Comment: I'd say mark.js's default behavior is nonobvious, and probably stupid, in such cases as yours.