# mark.js problem jumping to highlighted elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mark.js

We use mark.js to highlight searched text in our documents and jump to them - using the example from  http://jsfiddle.net/wy3tbvnq/2/.

Please search: "Lorem ipsum" -> **highlighting is perfect**, but jumping to text fragments jumps to **"Lorem", then "ipsum", then "lorem ipsum"**. It should be jumping to **Lorem ipsum** and next **Lorem ipsum**.

My problem is, that we have text which is spread over more than one span-tag. Like `<span>lorem</span><span>ipsum</span>` and we search for lorem ipsum. works perfectly with highlighting, but jumping to the searched text leads in jump to "lorem" and jump to "ipsum" - because they have both a class for highlighting.

Comment: just false the 'separateWordSearch' properties in js i.e. separateWordSearch: false

Comment: Addes some infos in my posting above. Don't know how to solve this problem...

Comment: written "highlighting is perfect" and while searching cause, while checking the fiddle, highlight also shows both words i.e. 'Lorem', 'Ipsum and 'Lorem ipsum'. that means highlight wrongly show.

Comment: Oh I forgot some settings: http://jsfiddle.net/wy3tbvnq/2/ is correct now...

Comment: Hi @anm, every thing I tried(added properties:  accuracy: "exactly"), but something issue, you can check this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38622653/mark-js-highlighting-specific-words   or you can directly question in mark js blog.

Answer (score 0):

Just false the properties, check the updated :- [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/973gdh8g/)

```
$content.unmark({
  done: function() {
    $content.mark(searchVal, {
      separateWordSearch: false,  //update this properties
      done: function() {
        $results = $content.find("mark");
        currentIndex = 0;
        jumpTo();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

`

Comment: But then i can't find the phrases in tags - but i need to.

Here is my example: https://jsfiddle.net/86gorcd9/ (search for "Lorem ipsum")

Comment: checked, after disabled the properties and I searched "Lorem Ipsum", it searches the exact word and highlight. If I searched only Lorem or Ipsum, then it shows accordingly.             And if enable the properties, it breaks the phrase into words and searches the first and then second (do not check the whole word).

Comment: Can you give more described example that what we entered in text , then what you want in search option i.e. what will be the first and then second, third etc.

Comment: we are nearer to answer, maybe I am not understood clearly.

Comment: I want to find the splittet "Lorem ipsum" and the not splittet "Lorem ipsum" as it does in my example. But jumping leads into jumps to "Lorem", "ipsum" (splittet) and "Lorem ipsum" (else).

I need to find all "Lorem ipsum" (also splittet ones) - and I need to jump to the whole phrase - splittet or not.

I'm sorry if that was not described properly.

Comment: sorry not to understand, can you edit your question and give the example that if search textbox have 'lorem' or 'ipsum' or 'lorem ipsum' text, then there is a paragraph which has both values, then where it will be jump first and then second? I guess, there is no issue in highlighting.

Comment: I changed jsfiddle link in my posting. Highlighting is perfect. Jumping to the found elements is not perfect, as described: jumping to text fragments jumps to "Lorem", then "ipsum", then "lorem ipsum". It should jump only to "Lorem ipsum" parts.